# How can I attach two attached behaviors to one XAML element?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, attachedbehaviors

I've implemented the [attached command behavior pattern found here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) and it **works well** to allow e.g. a Border to have a left- or right-click event that fires in the ViewModel:

**XAML:**

```
<Border Background="Yellow" Width="350" Margin="0,0,10,0" Height="35" CornerRadius="2"
        c:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
        c:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding PressedLeftButton}"
        c:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="MainBorder123">
    <TextBlock Text="this is the click area"/>
</Border>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public ICommand PressedLeftButton { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{

    Output = "original value";

    PressedLeftButton = new SimpleCommand
    {
        ExecuteDelegate = parameterValue => {
            Output = String.Format("left mouse button was pressed at {0} and sent the parameter value \"{1}\"", DateTime.Now.ToString(), parameterValue.ToString());
        }
    };
}
```

However, **how do I attach two attached behaviors to one element**, e.g. I want to do something like the following but it of course gives me an error:

```
<Border Background="Yellow" Width="350" Margin="0,0,10,0" Height="35" CornerRadius="2"
        c:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
        c:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding PressedLeftButton}"
        c:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="MainBorder123"
        c:CommandBehavior.Event="MouseRightButtonDown" 
        c:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding PressedRighttButton}"
        c:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="MainBorder123"
        >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you sent contains that very answer. You can use the CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors capabilities in ACB v2.

```
   <Border Background="Yellow" Width="350" Margin="0,0,10,0" Height="35" CornerRadius="2" x:Name="test">
       <local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
               <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Action="{Binding DoSomething}" CommandParameter="An Action on MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
               <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="A Command on MouseRightButtonDown"/>
       </local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
       <TextBlock Text="MouseDown on this border to execute the command"/>
   </Border>
```

Comment: that was it, thanks, funny though that my XAML editor gives me the error "The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'CommandBehaviorCollection'." although I can run and compile it fine, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

"that was it, thanks, funny though that my XAML editor gives me the error "The attachable property 'Behaviors' was not found in type 'CommandBehaviorCollection'." although I can run and compile it fine, why is that?"

The reason is that the code that allows the command behavior collection (which is an attached property *collection*) is actualy sort of a XAML loophole.  You can read more about that here:
http://wekempf.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!D18C3EC06EA971CF!468.entry?sa=276442122