# How to add a Command to the items in a databound TreeView

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, treeview, command, cag

How can I add WPF [`DelegateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707894.aspx)s to the items in a [`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) bound to an [`XmlDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx)? I'm using the MVVM pattern and Composite WPF and I want the command to be called when the user double-clicks on an item in the `TreeView`.

---

I have a `TreeView` defined in XAML whose `DataContext` is set to the `XmlDataProvider`:

```
<TreeView
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/SomeTopElement/*}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="SomeElement"
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=child::*}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@SomeAttribute}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

In other parts of the code I simply bind to a `DelegateCommand` in the ViewModel:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding NewCommand}" Header="_New" />
```

How can this be done with the above `TreeView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Attached Command Behavior pattern. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035023/firing-a-double-click-event-from-a-wpf-listview-item-using-mvvm) answers a similar problem, but within a ListView.

Comment: I also found another question on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926451/how-can-i-attach-two-attached-behaviors-to-one-xaml-element) and an example of general Attached Behaviors with a TreeView (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx)

Comment: @emddudley: yes, your 1st link is the one I used in one of my projects to add a double-clic command to a listbox and it work very well