# wpf eventsetter handler binding in style

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a style, and I want to bind a command to the `EventSetter`'s `Handler` with `RelativeSource`. The command is in the viewModel.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemTextBlockEventSetterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                 Handler="{Binding TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>
```

The problem is that I get an error, because something is wrong with this (maybe it's not possible to do this in such easy way)

I've googled a lot before, and I found the `AttachedCommandBehaviour`, but I think it doesn't work with style.

Could you give some hints on how to solve this problem?

**Update  13/10/2011**

I found this in the MVVM Light Toolkit `EventToCommand` example program:

```
        <Button Background="{Binding Brushes.Brush1}"
            Margin="10"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
            Content="Simple Command"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to activate command">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SimpleCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

But here, the binding isn't in the style. How can I put this `EventToCommand` to the style of the button?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right now you are binding the `MouseLeftButtonDown` Event to `TextBlock.TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand`. `TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand` is not a valid property for a TextBlock, nor does it sound like it's an Event Handler.

I use the [AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/) all the time in styles for hooking up a Command to an Event. The syntax usually looks like this (note the `DataContext`in the Command Binding):

```
<Style x:Key="ItemTextBlockEventSetterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Command"
            Value="{Binding DataContext.TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</Style>
```

The alternative is to hook the EventSetter up to an event in the code-behind, and process the command from there:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemTextBlockEventSetterStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                 Handler="TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
</Style>
```

Event handler in code behind...

```
void TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBlock;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        MyViewModel vm = tb.DataContext as MyViewModel;

        if (vm != null && TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand != null
            && TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand.CanExecute(null))
        {
            vm.TextBlockMouseLeftButtonDownCommand.Execute(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea to put the command execution to the event, but I will try the AttachCommandBehavior tomorrow!

Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: AttachCommandBehavior works perfectly. One thing that I'm not sure how to solve. I want to bind commands not only for one event, and I found this kind of solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926451/how-can-i-attach-two-attached-behaviors-to-one-xaml-element

It's really good, but how can I put this CommandBehaviorCollection to the style?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: @ZoltánBarna It does not appear to work in Styles or Templates

Comment: Hello Rachel, thank you very much. I had the exact same problem as the OP, and where <InvokeCommandAction> from System.Windows.Interactivity fails, AttachedCommandBehavior works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using MVVM, I suggest you [Galasoft MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) [`EventToCommand`](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx)

Comment: I saw the example with the rectangle and the eventriggers, and it's working, with the eventsetters as well?

Answer (score 0):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795978/4254572) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728205/4254572) does the trick without any external tool kits/libraries. However, it does not use `RelativeSource`, and it is not 100% MVVM. It requires one line of code in a code-behind event handler.